# Standard Analyser in lucene

Tags: lucene

is standard Analyzer in lucene is equall to

```
Select * from table where name Like raaga
```

will it searches only the exact match alone

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is: No.
You are comparing apples and oranges.
Here is [the StandardAnalyzer API](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_1/api/core/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardAnalyzer.html).
Here is a [Lucene tutorial](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe-book/lucene-3-tutorial.pdf) to give some context to the analyzer/query parser/search.

Answer (score 0):

Analyzers are used for the tokenization of the Query for the QuerySearch phase. It is also used for the tokenization phase for the analyzed fields. 
Your searches would depend on the type of Query you are running.